# Why my spring application don't start in a wildfly container?

Tags: spring, docker, deployment, wildfly, java-11

I'm trying to deploy a Spring application in a Wildfly container, but when start container the application don't start correctly.

I tried some tutorials that only write the SpringBootApplication main class extending SpringBootServletInitializer and added spring-boot-starter-web dependency removing tomcat and adding javax.servlet-api works fine, but when I put this settings to my project it's don't work

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>br.com.site</groupId>
    <artifactId>oAuth2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>oAuth2</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <javax.activation.version>1.1.1</javax.activation.version>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>3.2.3</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <jaxb.api.version>2.3.0</jaxb.api.version>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.activation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.name}</warName>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>jdk.unsupported</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                     <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SpringBootApplication

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class OAuth2Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuth2Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(OAuth2Application.class);
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/base-jdk:11

# Set the WILDFLY_VERSION env variable
ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 17.0.1.Final
ENV WILDFLY_SHA1 eaef7a87062837c215e54511c4ada8951f0bd8d5
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly

USER root

RUN cd $HOME \
    && curl -O https://download.jboss.org/wildfly/$WILDFLY_VERSION/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && sha1sum wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz | grep $WILDFLY_SHA1 \
    && tar xf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && mv $HOME/wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION $JBOSS_HOME \
    && rm wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && chown -R jboss:0 ${JBOSS_HOME} \
    && chmod -R g+rw ${JBOSS_HOME}

ENV LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND true

USER jboss

EXPOSE 8080

ADD oAuth2.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Wildfly Logs

```
12:47:02,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "oAuth2.war" (runtime-name: "oAuth2.war")
12:47:03,148 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
12:47:03,267 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.2) 
12:47:08,139 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /content/oAuth2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:47:08,149 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in /content/oAuth2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
12:47:09,479 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:47:09,502 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:47:09,532 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:47:09,534 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:47:09,539 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpRequest$RequestAsyncListener due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
12:47:09,801 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-4) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Infinity Minus ONE +2' 9.4.14.Final
12:47:09,844 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment oAuth2.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
12:47:10,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
12:47:10,606 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Handler java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler is not defined
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (vfs:/content/oAuth2.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: Hi Leonardo, have you tried this official image? [Wildfly Oficial Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/)
`FROM jboss/wildfly
 ADD your-awesome-app.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes, my dockerfile is the same of official jboss repository https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly

Comment: So, do you have the need to execute as jboss user? Because it seems that you dont need to use the CMD part, although you want to extend your image like they said here: https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/wildfly#extending-the-image , have you tried it?

Comment: So, another thing is, why you are using the RUN command? Since you just have to move your .war to the deployments folder? Your dockerfile are using jboss/base-jdk, instaead of jboss/wildfly

Comment: I don't need to use jboss user, I only reproduced the official jboss dockerfile

Comment: I tried only move the .war file to deployments folder but without success. I used this Dockerfile now

`FROM jboss/wildfly 
ADD myApp.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

Comment: So, it worked properly?

Comment: No, it's still happening the same thing that I reported in the question

Comment: Can you post the updated Dockerfile on the question? Also, you need to use a web-container for your application? Because most springboot Dockerfiles uses java command.

Comment: I tried this Dockerfile `FROM jboss/wildfly ADD myApp.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/`

Comment: Can you try this? 

`FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]` 

**Lets try do it without wildfly, also you can remove SpringBootServletInitializer**

Comment: Yes, but I'm using java 11 and really need to use wildfly

Comment: Interesting, when using the oficial Dockerfile the error is the same as the original that you used?

Comment: Yes, the application stay like myApp.war.deployed, but the Spring don't start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. Removing this dependency the application works fine

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.svenkubiak</groupId>
    <artifactId>embedded-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```